# How to check if the swf of Xcelsius embeded on html is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, loaded, xcelsius

Ive created a swf file with Xcelsius. How can I check when it s is fully loaded?

I tried jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("document ready occurred!");
});

$(window).load(function() {
      alert("window load occurred!");
});
```

but i get the alert before the swf is ready

Any javascript alternative?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems you can´t actually check when its fully loaded. But if you want to do something after it´s loaded you can use a function in javascript with **setInternval** and just pass the attribute until the movie gets it

```
function setAttribute(){
      var attributes = {
       id: "movie",
        name: "movie"
      };
      swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "movie", "1025", "678", "9.0.0", attributes);
       var i = 1;
          var sInt = setInterval(function() { 
            if(i >= 10) {
              clearInterval(sInt);
            }else{
              i++;
           }
            //here goes the parameter you want to pass to the movie
       }, 500);  //increase the interval if you need it
    }
```